# HTML5 Drag with contents

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I want to use HTML5 native drag. I want to drag an item with its contents.

For example:

```
<div draggable="true">
    <div>
      1
    </div>
    <div>
      2
    </div>
    <div>
      3
    </div>
</div>
```

This will only drag the containing div empty.

How can I tell it to drag the div with all of its contents?

Comment: How are you telling it to drag at the moment?  Just the attribute?

Comment: yes, this is HTML5 api

Comment: So how are you able to tell what has been dragged?

Answer (score -1):

You can use j query ui draggable instead of HTML5 dragable. Its easy to use and you can find many options in these library.

Find the example here
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: I know it. ui draggable is not good when you set overflow to scroll.

Comment: If you provide me the whole code then I ll able to create this issue at my end and then I ll solve this issue